# SQL inner joins vs LIKE does not return rows

Tags: mysql, inner-join, sql-like

Is there someone out there that can explain why my query won't work?

```
SELECT country.Country, city.City, location.Adress, museuminfo.Phone, museuminfo.Mail, museuminfo.Homepage, museum.MuseumName, museum.Description, museum.Collections, photo.PhotoRef 
FROM country 
INNER JOIN city 
ON country.CountryCode=city.CountryCode 
INNER JOIN location 
ON city.CityId = location.CityId 
INNER JOIN museuminfo 
ON location.LocationId = museuminfo.LocationId 
INNER JOIN museum 
ON museuminfo.MuseumInfoId = museum.MuseumInfoId 
INNER JOIN photo 
ON museuminfo.MuseumInfoId = photo.MuseumInfoId 
WHERE 
(MuseumName LIKE '%classic%') 
OR (Description LIKE '%classic%') 
OR (Collections LIKE '%classic%')
AND museum.LanguageCode = 'EN'
```

I have a shortened version which works fine but you can only search one table at a time:

```
SELECT * FROM museum 
WHERE (MuseumName LIKE '%classic%') 
OR (Description LIKE '%classic%') 
OR (Collections LIKE '%classic%') 
AND museum.LanguageCode = 'EN'
```

Please help me :-(

Comment: What is the query supposed to do?

Comment: `INNER JOIN` produces rows for matching rows on both sides. If there are no matching rows for any of the join conditions then you will get no results. Try using `OUTER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Come back when you have a shortened version that DOESN'T work and you can explain what you are trying to do and what's going wrong.

Comment: Perhaps you need brackets. `(...OR ...OR...) AND ...`

Comment: It did work to user other joins than inner join. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not absolute sure unless you provide some sample data and let know what the query actually trying to achieve ... but try changing your `WHERE` conditions as below

```
WHERE 
(museum.MuseumName LIKE '%classic%' 
OR museum.Description LIKE '%classic%'
OR museum.Collections LIKE '%classic%')
AND museum.LanguageCode = 'EN'
```

(OR)

```
WHERE museum.LanguageCode = 'EN'
AND 
(museum.MuseumName LIKE '%classic%' 
OR museum.Description LIKE '%classic%'
OR museum.Collections LIKE '%classic%')
```

Comment: Yes sorry, the query is for getting museums through a search which originally generated this query. And as i said i have the shortened version working because (my guess) it only grabs one table without all the joins which i think messes it up. The alternative code you wrote did not work either, sadly.. I see some people mentioning using outer- og lef-joins. But i don't think i fully understand them so i think i'm going to research abit! But thank you for the response!